# TortoiseGit clone option is unavailable in right-click context menu

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have installed Git 2.5.2 64-bit and TortoiseGit 1.8.16.0 64-bit onto my Windows 7 64 bit computer.  I would like to clone a repository but when I right click in windows explorer, I am not seeing an option to clone a repo:

[image: context menu image]

I have gone to TortoiseGit -> Settings -> General -> Context Menu and made sure that the Clone option is checked:

[image: tortoise git settings menu]

I am able to clone a repo using git:

```
git clone user@location.com:Group/repo.git myrepo
```

I can also get TortoiseGit's clone dialog to open via command line:

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:clone
```

but I can't seem to get it to work with TortoiseGit's shell integration.

Does anyone know why the clone option is not showing up?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. "Hide Menus for unversioned paths" is selected, so no TortoiseGit menu is shown for paths where no git working tree could be found (you need to press shift there)
2. Within a working tree (in a non-ignored folder) no clone is available in the context menu. However, with newer versions (IIRC >= 2.2) also for versioned folders the Git clone entry can be shown by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while opening the context menu.

---

If you want to clone a checked out repository, navigate to a clean new directory, right-click and you will see the clone command in the context menu where you can, then, select the path of the repository you want to clone.

Comment: After I unchecked "Hide Menus for unversioned paths" and saved the setting, both the right click context menu and the shift+right click context menu still are missing the clone option even when there is no git working tree in that location.

Comment: I did find out that I had a _.git_ folder in my user directory.  This was causing the _Git Sync..._ and _Git Commit..._ options in the context menu when I was thinking I was outside a working tree.  Still no option for clone when I'm pressing shift.

Comment: As I said: Clone won't show up in versioned folders - it's coded that way.

Comment: Per your comment, I deleted the .git folder in my user directory so that the make clone available again (still wasn't visible).  I then unchecked the Clone option in the Set Extend Menu Item settings page and finally rechecked the Clone option in the Context Menu settings page in order for it to show up in the right click context menu. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but this time the .git folder was on my Desktop, not in my homedir (%USERPROFILE%).  It was hard to remove because it was "hidden", but after removing it, I was able to Git Clone without having to resort to shift-right-click, and the other Git commands stopped showing up in folders where they shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

before
*** Right mouse button
[image]

after

*** Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>  with Right mouse button
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  When I uncheck the *Clone...* option from the context menu setting dialog, it appears in the shift+right click context menu in the TortoiseGit folder of the context menu will show the *Clone...* option. (this is also true for the *Create repository here...* option). This was a bit confusing since the context menu setting dialog's hover tip is "Check those menu entries you want to appear in the top context menu instead of the TortoiseGit submenu".  I was expecting them to show up in the top right-click context menu (above the TortoiseGit submenu) but they didn't. By checking those options they were omitted from the TortoiseGit submenu so they seemed to disappear.  I can rest easy now that I can find the *Clone...* and *Create repository here...* options, but I would still be curious to know why they aren't showing up in the top context menu.

Comment: This is not fully correct as the pre-conditions are not correctly stated in this answer. See above.

Comment: Context Menu: Choose the ones you use most often
Context Menu 2: Uncheck all items except for anything you never use.

Answer (score 0):

For those reader who are still looking for solutions in this problem, I hope this link could help you too:

https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/4423#issuecomment-362666877