# Why won't tortoisegit clone option show in right-click context menu

Tags: menu, clone, tortoisegit

I saw this question posted here, but the answers do not help me.  I have been trying for hours to get this to work, and it just doesn't.

How can I get clone to appear in the menu when I right-click a folder? None of the previous answers to this question on this forum have corrected the problem (Hide Menus for unversioned paths is NOT selected). This is a new folder that I just created, and I don't see where it is versioned...here is the old question with suggestions that do not work: [tortoisegit clone option is unavailable in right-click context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046508/tortoisegit-clone-option-is-unavailable-in-right-click-context-menu)

Comment: Does clone show up when you press shift while opening the context menu?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, but resolved it with the recommendation above. Just select 'Shift' when opening the menu and the 'Clone' option will appear.