# TortoiseGit has no option to clone a repository

Tags: windows, git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have moved from the sturdy and reliable Tortoise HG to TortoiseGit. However, I can not find a way to clone a repository. There is no option for it when I right-click nor is there a gui. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Below is what I see after I right-click.

[image]

Then navigating to > TortoiseGit I see the following (No clone option);

[image]

I have also tried adjusting the settings but this doesn't have any effect.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tortoisegit clone option is unavailable in right-click context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046508/tortoisegit-clone-option-is-unavailable-in-right-click-context-menu)

Comment: Thanks. I read that prior to posting and no it doesn't help solve it. Changing the settings as suggested does not have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you click in an existing git repository. Therefore, `git clone` is unavailable. Navigate to a clean new directory such as `C:\MyTestDir`, right-click and you'll see the `git clone` command in the context menu.

Comment: Why add a new answer when this is a duplicate question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34047472/3906760)?

Comment: @MrTux I cannot confirm whether its the same question or not. If it is the same question then it will be closed as a dupe anyway.